# not able to pass particular order_id from multiple order_id in pop box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

there are many order_id but want to pass that id to the popup box which i select

```
<a rel="dialog" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?=$order_id ?>" href="#mymodal" data-target="#myModal" ><?php echo "<br> $order_id </br>";?></a>
```

//this is the script i used for passing the particular value to the pop up box

```
<script>

            $(document).ready(function(){
            ...
            $("a[rel=dialog]").each(function(){
               var id = this.getAttribute("data-id");
               $('#products_id_textbox').val(id);
               $('#products_modal_box').dialog('close');
            });
            </script>



             <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" >
                <tr style=" background-color:#00AAAD; color:#FFF; ">

                    <td>Passenger Name </td>
                    <td>Mobile No</td>
                </tr>
                <?php echo $order_id;?>
```

Comment: Why are you using `each()`

Comment: because there are multiple value one id

Comment: can  anyone help me out with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the code snippet & check output. I hope this is what you want:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("a[rel=dialog]").click(function(){
            var id =$(this).attr("data-id");
            $('#products_id_textbox').val(id);
            console.log("Order id-"+id);
       });  
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <a rel="dialog" data-toggle="modal" data-id="1" href="#mymodal" data-target="#myModal" >1</a>
 <a rel="dialog" data-toggle="modal" data-id="2" href="#mymodal" data-target="#myModal" >2</a>
 <a rel="dialog" data-toggle="modal" data-id="3" href="#mymodal" data-target="#myModal" >3</a>
 <a rel="dialog" data-toggle="modal" data-id="4" href="#mymodal" data-target="#myModal" >4</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         Order Id : <input type="text" id="products_id_textbox"/>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```